# Xcode - Parse string into usable data structure

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I have a string (snippet below) that I know is valid json by [parsing it here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#). The final parsing that I want to achieve is [based off this PHP code](https://github.com/viktor0011/Google-Maps-scrape/blob/master/scrape.php). I can not seem to keep xcode happy when I try the following code, as I seem to continue to make array's of `<Any>` and either get the error `Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts` or an unwrapping of a nil

any thoughts how to parse this would be greatly appreciated.

```
if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!,options : .allowFragments) as? Array<Any> {
                let a = jsonArray[0] as? Array<Any>
                let a = jsonArray[0] as? Array<Any>
                let b =  a?[1] as? Array<Any>
                let c = b?[1] as? Array<Array<Any>>

}
```

Snippet - [full string here](https://gist.github.com/cgmckeever/54a194b68391062af2fcbe7408f916d9)

```
[["comic books",[["","","","","","","","","Ba6eX5HWBc3btAa6mJ_4Cg","0ahUKEwjR7NSWsOHsAhXNLc0KHTrMB68QmBkIAigA",["comic books",0]
]
,["","","","","","","","","Ba6eX5HWBc3btAa6mJ_4Cg","0ahUKEwjR7NSWsOHsAhXNLc0KHTrMB68QmBkIBCgB","","","","",["Ba6eX5HWBc3btAa6mJ_4Cg","0ahUKEwjR7NSWsOHsAhXNLc0KHTrMB68Q8BcIBSgAMAA",["330 Army Trail Rd","Glendale Heights, IL 60139"]
,"",["","","",["https://www.google.com/search?q\u003dGot+Comics+Inc,+330+Army+Trail+Rd,+Glendale+Heights,+IL+60139\u0026ludocid\u003d7330282631276370350#lrd\u003d0x880fac8c25bbd32b:0x65ba6537347199ae,1","105
```

Comment: That's terrible JSON format.

Comment: oh yeah it is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's declare the data type:

```swift
struct Item {
    let name: String?
    let location: String?
    let phone: String?
}
```

Using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), you can nicely convert the PHP code into something like this:

```swift
var items = [Item]()
if let json = try? JSON(data: jsonData), let arr = json[0][1].array {
    for itemArray in arr {
        guard let itemDetails = itemArray[14].array else { continue }
        let name = itemDetails[11].string
        let location = itemDetails[18].string
        let phone = itemDetails[178][0][0].string
        items.append(Item(name: name, location: location, phone: phone))
    }
}
```

For fun, here's a shorter, more functional, less readable, implementation of the above code:

```swift
let items = (try? JSON(data: jsonData))?[0][1].array?
    .compactMap { $0[14].array }
    .map { Item(name: $0[11].string, location: $0[18].string, phone: $0[178][0][0].string) }
    ?? []
```